# Linux (POP OS) JetBrains applications has no top toolbar?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

So I just installed Pop OS to my system, but notice, that neither of JetBrains apps has a top toolbar. Firstly, it's just a dark line, but after some time it just disappears.

Tried to install the software in a different ways, but got the same results. I cannot move the window, exit or minimize (since there is no options, of course), only resize it. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is wondering, the problem was, that "Show Window Titles" was disabled by default for me. You can turn it on on Extensions -> Pop Shell -> Show Window Titles.

[image]